# Null values while looping uninstall keys for FireFox

Tags: c#

I have the following code:
The values are displayed as follows in the debugger:
FF86_version "31.0.1" 
FF86_name "Firefox"
displayFF86version "null"
displayFF86name "null"

```
    public static bool checkFF86version(string FF86_name, string FF86_version)
    {
        RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
        .OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        //.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        string displayFF86version;
        string displayFF86name;

        if (key != null)
        {
            foreach (RegistryKey subkey in key.GetSubKeyNames().Select(keyName => key.OpenSubKey(keyName)))
            {
                displayFF86name = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
                if (displayFF86name != null && displayFF86name.Contains(FF86_name))
                {
                    displayFF86version = subkey.GetValue("DisplayVersion") as string;

                if (displayFF86version.Equals(FF86_version))
                    {
                        var version = displayFF86version; //Comes from the Registry
                        var parsedversion = Version.Parse(version);

                        var minimumversion = new Version(FF86_version); //Static Version Check

                        if (parsedversion >= minimumversion)                           
                            return true;                  
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I am trying to see if "Firefox" is installed. If it is detected compare the DisplayVersion to see if it is > or < the version identified as displayed below:

```
         if (checkFF86version("Firefox", "31.0.1"))
            listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { ImageIndex = 0, Text = "Firefox is Installed and is the latest version" });
         else
             listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { ImageIndex = 0, Text = "Firefox needs updated" });
```

I have solved this issue, I thought I would post the resolution for anyone else that may have this problem. It seems that the answers are hard to find. This may save you some time. Special thanks to "CodeK" on (CodeProject) for the help on this solution. Without him I could have never completed it.

```
        public void GetNameAndVersion()
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey iRegKey = null;
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey iSubKey = null;
            string eValue = null;
            string eVersion = null;
            string regpath = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall";
            iRegKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regpath);
            string[] subkeys = iRegKey.GetSubKeyNames();
            bool includes = false;
            foreach (string subk in subkeys)
            {
                iSubKey = iRegKey.OpenSubKey(subk);
                 eValue = Convert.ToString(iSubKey.GetValue("DisplayName", ""));
                 eVersion = Convert.ToString(iSubKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion", ""));

                 if (eValue != null && eValue.Contains("Firefox"))
                 {
                    var version = eVersion;
                     var parsedversion = Version.Parse(version);
                     var minimumversion = new Version("35.0.1");

                     if (parsedversion >= minimumversion)
                         listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { ImageIndex = 0, Text = "Firefox is the latest version or newer" });
                     else if (parsedversion < minimumversion)
                         listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { ImageIndex = 0, Text = "Firefox needs reinstalled" });

                 else
                     includes = false;
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please write a better title. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: I have updated my title, is that a little better?

Comment: Are you getting a `NullReferenceException`?  Is the code running but not returning the right value?  Those values may be null on loop entry since you don't give them default values.

Comment: I am trying to loop through all the keys and find "Firefox" once I have found "Firefox" I need to compare it's DisplayVersion with the min. specified. I am sure I have this all jacked up!

Comment: I am not getting an Exception, and the code is running fine, but always returning false due to NULL key data

Comment: @MichaelMiller You should update your question with that and take out anything about the strings, it seems like your real question is what the correct path for the registry key you want is.

Comment: No, The key names can change as software is updated. Take Firefox for example, the key name has the version in it. I need to loop through the keys and find Contains "Firefox"

Comment: The entire concept of this question is guaranteed to give unreliable results for multiple reasons, most obviously for the simple reason that just because Firefox has been made available for a system, that doesn't mean it exists in the registry. It might have come through PortableApps, for instance.

Comment: In this particular case the check will only be conducted within a known environment. I would never have a portable App in the known environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue, I thought I would post the resolution for anyone else that may have this problem. It seems that the answers are hard to find. This may save you some time. Special thanks to "CodeK" on (CodeProject) for the help on this solution. Without him I could have never completed it.

```
    public void GetNameAndVersion()
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey iRegKey = null;
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey iSubKey = null;
        string eValue = null;
        string eVersion = null;
        string regpath = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall";
        iRegKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regpath);
        string[] subkeys = iRegKey.GetSubKeyNames();
        bool includes = false;
        foreach (string subk in subkeys)
        {
            iSubKey = iRegKey.OpenSubKey(subk);
             eValue = Convert.ToString(iSubKey.GetValue("DisplayName", ""));
             eVersion = Convert.ToString(iSubKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion", ""));

             if (eValue != null && eValue.Contains("Firefox"))
             {
                var version = eVersion;
                 var parsedversion = Version.Parse(version);
                 var minimumversion = new Version("35.0.1");

                 if (parsedversion >= minimumversion)
                     listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { ImageIndex = 0, Text = "Firefox is the latest version or newer" });
                 else if (parsedversion < minimumversion)
                     listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { ImageIndex = 0, Text = "Firefox needs reinstalled" });

             else
                 includes = false;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

}